# regex to match either single, double or triple digit

Tags: regex

I am trying to find all instances of places where (x,y) have been used in my code where x and y are integers.

I tried `[0-9]+,[0-9]+`

This could detect (0,2) (3,5) etc, but it doesnt detect

(0,50) or (255,255)

How do I make the check inclusive for all numbers?

This not a programming language, this for Notepad++ and I think I had to include white spaces \s* before and after the commas

Comment: What language are you using?  Not all languages support the same regex syntax...

Comment: Your regex should detect `255,255` just fine (although it would also find `9999,999999` and other, more-than-three-digit numbers.

Comment: not a programming language, needed it for a text editor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
\(\d{1,3},\d{1,3}\)
```

See it here in action: http://regexr.com?32jph

---

Here's the breakdown:

**`\(`** - matches a literal `(`
**`\d{1,3}`** - matches one to three digits
**`,`** - well, matches a literal `,`
**`\d{1,3}`** - again, matches one to three digits
**`\)`** - matches a literal `)`

Answer (score 4):

Use `\d` to match any digit, and curly braces to match 1-3 characters - `\d{1,3}`. For your full match use:

```
\d{1,3},\d{1,3}
```

If you want to include the parenthesis, they will need to be escaped:

```
\(\d{1,3},\d{1,3}\)
```